# Design assets for all screen unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a mobile game in Unity for Android and iOS, I already have my assets design for a device of `480*800` pixels, but when I launch my game in a biggest screen, the image is horrible.

I tried different technics to scale the camera, the images... without success. In `Android` there is multiple size of `drawables : hdpi, xxdpi`... and in `iOS` the images can't be the same for an `iPad` and an `iPhone`, so I did not understand, how I can load multiple images to fit all the screen resolution.

or How to make my assets to do that. Can you explain me please ?

Comment: well, one thing you could start with is reading about **Mip-Maps**. Then read about every setting in [**2D Texture Importer docs**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html). But other than that you'd have to come up with your own hacks to improve quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

400 pixels is ***incredibly small*** for game images these days. We rarely get or use anything less than 4K these days.

One thing: if it is actual "pixel art" (so, "retro" pixel art), you must use the **"point" enlarger to keep the "pixel shape" when you enlarge it**.

Note that pretty much everyone uses 2DToolkit with Unity for 2D projects. It creates sprite sheets for you. BUT it also has the concept of different sprite sheet sets for different screen sizes, if you are working on a pixel-perfect concept (as much as that has any meaning today).

Unity itself does not contain any "different sprites for different devices" concept, and this is one of the main reasons 2DToolkit remains so popular.

Finally note that: if you make computer games it is

## ...extremely difficult...

dealing with different screen ***ratios***.

Say you are making a side scroller: what does it "mean" that some players have *a wider screen than others*?  What should you "see" on a wide screen versus a normal screen in, say, GTA?

This can involve a huge amount of conceptual work and programming. This affects everyone who makes games, from the kid on the corner to Nintendo. There is no "simple solution".